# TortoiseSVN could not begin a transaction

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, putty

I have just created an svn repository on a remote secure server (You need a user name and a password to access it) using puTTY:

```
svnadmin create repo_name
```

Then, I created a working copy using the import command, and pointing to the repository. The working copy then shows up, obviously completely empty besides the .svn folder.

Now, I want to create the structure, adding the branches, tags, and trunk folder. However, when I open the Repo-browser and try to create a new folder I end up with this error:
[image]
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the logs on the server side. Most likely, there is a problem with permissions. See this post https://serverfault.com/questions/625579/svn-cant-open-file-var-www-svn-repo-db-txn-current-lock-permission-denied

Answer (score 1):

Please check if there is enough space in SVN Server. This is space issue only.

Answer (score 0):

1. [`svn import`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) does not create Working Copy, just add revision into repository from a set of unversioned files
2. Even after you created repository with `svnadmin create` this repository have to be accessible with any possible transport (and you have to know URL|protocol)
   If you used local access (with `file:///`) you have to check ownership and permissions of all objects in repository (as files and folders)… and `.svn` subdir isn't repository

You have to write more technical details if you want to get help here

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the folder owners and permission.
In my case it's require Apache user owner with 0755 permission for "/svn/repo/"